# Compare differences of branches and categorise

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-diff, github-api-v3

I'm new to python.  Suppose test file changes goes to testing category, buildpack or code level changes goes to functional changes. I'm trying to find the difference between two branch (master, feature) of a project then read the code differences and categorise them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [tortoise](https://tortoisesvn.net/TortoiseMerge.html) for code differences and [gitk command](https://riptutorial.com/git/example/18336/gitk-and-git-gui) for changes happened in the repo

Comment: Hi @manaclan, Thanks for suggestions. But All I have do using github api and python code. Also , need to look the file difference and categorise it